# Convert IEnumerable<int[][]> to int[][]

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, jagged-arrays

Initializing a jagged array in C# from an XML file.  The following code seems to work to create the data structure I want, from what I can see in the debugger, but the code returns a value of type IEnumerable.

```
var ia = (from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Descendants("doc")
          select (
              from rows in e.Elements("rows")
              select (
                  from cols in rows.Elements("cols")
                  select int.Parse(cols.Value)
              ).ToArray()
          ).ToArray());
```

If I throw in an extra `.ToArray()` on the end (thanks to other StackOverflow articles), I get back `int[1][][]`.

Any ideas on how to get the code working so I can simply write `int[][] array = (from e in...` etc.?

Comment: you have descendants * rows * cols. Thats 3D, and you want 2D. That's the real problem. My guess is you have just a single doc, right?

Comment: You have three levels of enumeration, so there will be three levels of depth in the jagged array. You can have multiple "docs", which can have multiple "rows", which can have multiple "cols". Which arrays do you want to combine so that you only have two levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always only one `doc` element you can do following:

```
var ia = (from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Descendants("doc")
          select (
              from rows in e.Elements("rows")
              select (
                  from cols in rows.Elements("cols")
                  select int.Parse(cols.Value)
              ).ToArray()
          ).First().ToArray());
```

If you're expecting more then one `doc` element you can make additional `SelectMany` call:

```
var ia = (from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Descendants("doc")
          select (
              from rows in e.Elements("rows")
              select (
                  from cols in rows.Elements("cols")
                  select int.Parse(cols.Value)
              ).ToArray()
          ).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray());
```

Comment: <hits head> Yes, only one `doc` element.  I guess I should re-think using `Descendants` in this context.  Thanks for the fix, everyone.  You guys came back so quickly...!

Comment: @Yes, you should definitely think about **not** using `Descendants` like that. [Why (or when) you should/shouldn't use Descendants() method](http://mjuraszek.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-not-use-descendants-method.html)

Comment: Good article, Marcin.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone reading this in future, here's the final code that worked, using Marcin's article:  `int[][] ia = (from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Element("doc").Elements("rows") select (
 from cols in e.Elements("cols") select int.Parse(cols.Value)).ToArray()).ToArray();`

Comment: If `doc` is the root element on your document you can change `Load().Element("doc").Elements()` to `Load().Root.Elements()`

Answer (score 0):

You have descendants * rows * cols. Thats 3D, and you want 2D. I guess you expect just a single "doc" descendant in your xml file. You can verify that with `Single` which fails when there's more than one item in the collection, meaning more than one "doc":

```
var ia = (from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Descendants("doc")
    select (
        from rows in e.Elements("rows")
        select (
            from cols in rows.Elements("cols")
            select int.Parse(cols.Value)).ToArray()).Single().ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks - will check this out, too, i3arnon.